# I want to load a csv file providing the path and file name in a Prompt box, using Javascript during onLoad event and present the content in a div

Tags: javascript

I need to load a file on the OnLoad event. I need to get the file path using the javascript Prompt and load the file, presenting the content in a DIV.
My problem is in the file loading. I cant use the window manager to choose the file name.

Comment: There is a way to do this in Chrome (https://web.dev/file-system-access/) I don't know whether you can activate the FS API from this from `window.prompt` you may need to create an input and a submit button

Comment: What I need is this: var content=loadFile(prompt('what is the file path and name?'));

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you upload a file. Then where it console.logs(res) you can do any logic you want with the data from the file.

```js
    /* Native JS  
        
     */

    const readFile = (event) => {  
      //First File Upload
      let file = event.target.files[0]; 
      if (file) {   
        //reading File from User Input* 
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {   
          //Reading Txt File    
          let reader = new FileReader();      
            //Resolving On read 
          reader.onload =  (evt) => {      
            resolve(evt.target.result);      
          };     

          reader.readAsText(file);
          //reading file as txt*      
          reader.onerror = reject;   
        })    
            //Read data 
          .then(console.log(res))  
            //Catching Errors
          .catch((err) => {     
          console.log(err)
        });  
      }
    }

    document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

```html
    <div class="ui icon header">
        <i class="pdf file outline icon"></i>
          Upload Text Document Below
       <input type="file" accept="text/*" id="file" class="ui blue button"> 
    </div>
```

Comment: What I need is a "loadFile" function that do not use input file tag. Just get the file path and load the file. Thanks.

<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var content=loadFile(prompt('what is the file path and name?'));
            document.getElementById('content').inerHTML=content;
        </script>
        <script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.tabbable.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='content'></div>
    </body>
</html>